# Cannot Git Push from Xcode 5 using my user name

Tags: xcode, git, github

First thing I did is add a remote repository from `XCode->Preferences->Accounts` with the correct address, user name and password.

After this I go to `Source Control->Push` and it always ask me for the password for the `git` user, not my user, why is that ?

[image]

Comment: What git protocol do you use?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I am using ssh

Comment: Fixed it by creating my remote repo again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the best solution for repo's on github and bitbucket is to create an SSH key-pair with no password.

```
$ cd .ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f github_id_rsa
$ vi config
```

Then add the following:

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa
```

And to then refer to the repo as:

```
ssh://github/trojanfoe/myrepo
      ^^^^^^
(note that's the name of the config "alias", not github.com)
```

This works well in Xcode, however I see "green lights" next to the repo during a *pull*, but "red lights" next to the repo during a *push* (this might be a bug in Xcode 5.1 beta), but it works without complaint and without the need for a password, which is great if you use Jenkins to do your release builds.

The Repositories under *Preferences* > *Accounts* cannot connect using the ssh alias either, but strangely they function just fine when performing Source Control operations:

[image]

Comment: can you post your answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657022/update-tableview-if-data-is-changed-online). Now I understand what you were saying but needs your answer back... also sample link where such example is posted would be great...